# Is there a way to have the equivalent of a struct in Java 1.4?

Tags: java, struct

Using the common example of a Point (x, y) object, is there a way to have it as a struct in Java 1.4? The advantage would be that there would not be a separate memory allocation for the Point object because the struct would be part of the containing object. But it would still have member functions to access it.

I'm 98% certain the answer is no but hope springs eternal...

what/why:
In our code we have 100,000+ objects (about 12 - 14% of the total memory footprint) that is an int and a boolean. If that was a C# struct inside the object, it would reduce the number of objects. And... we are looking at making it just an int where 0x40000000 is the boolean value. But handling that is a lot easier if we have member methods for that int and it's treated as a struct.

Comment: You seem concerned about memory allocation...  Do you mean using "new"?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code describing what exactly a Java "struct" is?

Comment: Do you mean equivalent to a C# struct? A value type, no references, cannot be null, doesn't hit the garbage collector?

Comment: If what you're after is stack-allocated, value-type kinds of Objects, they don't exist in Java (even in most recent versions of Java). But don't worry too much: the GC is very efficient at collecting short-lived objects.

Comment: Short answer: no, make an object--what do you believe the issue is?

Answer (score 2):

There is no struct equivalent on Java now, although I believe that they have been hinted for future versions. Still have a look at the flyweight pattern, might be what you are looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern

Comment: Unfortunately these all have different values. Or to be more accurate, each can be set to a different value at any time.

Comment: well the pattern says that the objects are immutable but that you can change the reference to the object by getting a new one from the pool, are most of your 100k+ objects different?, can't you refactor it into parts that are pool-able separately?

Comment: It would probably be a pool of a couple of hundred. But that moves the issue because each set then becomes a map lookup and assignment. I think that would be worse than storing the primitives directly and having static methods to operate on them. Takes me back to the old days of C where the code I wrote was, in hindsight, about as object oriented as you could get with just structs.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to use `Object`s for general "structs".

However for simple data structures like pairs of `int`s, you can use a bit of trickery in order to save memory and increase speed.

```
int a = 9;
int b = 10;
long pair = (a << 32)|b;
```

This packs the 32 bits of `a` and `b` into a `long`. Here's how you extract them:

```
a = (int)(pair >> 32);
b = (int)pair;
```

Answer (score 1):

An addition to [tskuzzy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11164862/874577):  another possibility would be to lift the `int x` and `int y` fields from the `Point` class into any classes that need to store point values.

Edit in response to comments:

One thing you could do is to have each class that needs to store a single point value extend a `Point` class.  There would be no logical is-a relationship, but it gives you access to `Point` objects through a single interface.  This wouldn't work (I don't think) for any classes that need to store multiple point values, though.

Comment: That's what we're looking at doing. But we have a bunch of these in a class and so that all becomes messy. I hate to lose the cleanliness of an object interface. Oh well, life is imperfect.

Comment: You can still write an object that has a nice interface, but uses the more memory efficient implementation.